# creating extension using xsd:redefine and not using xsd:override

Tags: xml, xsd

I need help in using the xsd:redefine.
According to the manual, I can use xsd:redeine to add extension to the schema. 
for example, for Message, I have this definition:
`

```
<xsd:complexType name="MESSAGE_EXTENSION">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="MISMO" type="MISMO_BASE" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="OTHER" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:complexContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="OTHER_BASE"/>
                </xsd:complexContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="OTHER_BASE">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

`

Is there a way to use xsd:redefine to redefine the OTHER in the MESSAGE_EXTENSION to not use the OTHER_BASE as extension base, but use a new Complextype call MESSAGE_OTHER_BASE ?

```
`<xsd:complexType name="MESSAGE_OTHER_BASE">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="QUERYCRITERIA" type="mismo:QUERYCRITERIA" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>`
```

I can achieve the above using xsd:override as below:

```
<xsd:override schemaLocation="MISMO_3.4.0_B324.xsd">
    <xsd:complexType name="MESSAGE_EXTENSION">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="MISMO" type="mismo:MISMO_BASE" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="OTHER" type="mismo:MESSAGE_OTHER_BASE" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:override>
```

But xsd:override is only available in XSD 1.1. I cannot use XSD 1.1. I have to stick with redefine in XSD 1.0.

When I use xsd:redeine at the MESSAGE_EXTENSION level it will just add the QUERYCRITERIA as a sibling to the OTHER, not as a child.

And I should not extend the OTHER_BASE as it will affect all other part that uses extension.

thanks for your advice !